# Where is elasticsearch `bin/`?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

The ElasticSearch docs refer to a `bin/` directory, but I'm not sure where that is. I'm running on Ubuntu 17.10 and ES 6.1.1, started with `systemctl start elasticsearch`.

For example, from [the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/working-with-plugins.html#listing-plugins):

```
bin/logstash-plugin list 
bin/logstash-plugin list --verbose 
bin/logstash-plugin list '*namefragment*' 
bin/logstash-plugin list --group output
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the information provided I am guessing that you installed Elasticsearch via deb packages (from the repository or simply downloaded them). Then you probably installed Logstash in the same way, which places the `bin/` directory in `/usr/share/logstash/`. You should be able to see your plugins with

```
$ /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin list
```

If your installation process for Logstash was different, you can check with the [docs on directory layout](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.1/dir-layout.html#deb-layout).